# JMETER - INFLUXDB - GRAFANA

Tags: visual-studio-2022

HttpMetricsSender: Error writing metrics to influxDB Url: http://localhost:8086/api/v2/write?org=learning&bucket=jmeter, responseCode: 401, responseBody: {"error":"unable to parse authentication credentials"}

how can i reslove that issue from any one guys please